# Responsive Divs in HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My html has images which have their height and width hardcoded ( is a necessity because of the transition implemented on it). But three images are kept within a div. So is there a way to keep the container div to a specific height and width that makes is responsive to all the screen size and resizes ( if needed) the inner images. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us a code? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you set `img { max-width:100% , height:auto; }` within a container holder , that will make them responsive in every screen view-port.Because they'r taking the size of it's parent container.

Comment: Well I have to HARDCORDE the image height and width in the css files. It is essential for the fading affect to occur. So is there a way that the div makes them smaller or larger according to the screen size.